# How to install net link to use in a C program?

Tags: wireless, libraries

I want to install `libnl` package so I can use its APIs to communicate with wireless driver of my computer. I have checked the package status with `dpkg -s libnl-3-200`. The result is:

```
Package: libnl-3-200
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 168
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: libnl3
Version: 3.2.27-1ubuntu0.16.04.1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14)
Conffiles:
 /etc/libnl-3/classid 3e07259e58674631830b152e983ca995
 /etc/libnl-3/pktloc 7613dbc41b2dc3258195b6b6abd0f179
Description: library for dealing with netlink sockets
 This is a library for applications dealing with netlink sockets.
 The library provides an interface for raw netlink messaging and various
 netlink family specific interfaces.
Homepage: http://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/
Original-Maintainer: Heiko Stuebner <mmind@debian.org>
```

In order to write program, I need to include files like:

```
#include <netlink/netlink.h>
#include <netlink/cache.h>
#include <netlink/route/link.h>
```

But the `make` cannot find these header files and my `/usr/include/` does not have `netlink` folder. My `/usr/lib/` does not have anything with `libnl` in it. Should I install another package?

Comment: Yes: `libnl-3-dev`

Comment: Thanks! I installed it. For some reason the includes are installed in `/usr/include/libnl3/netlink` folder. This causes `make` to give me errors since other includes in included files assume `netlink` folder is in `/usr/include/` and not in `/usr/include/libnl3/`. Can I move `netlink` folder from `/usr/include/libnl3/` to `/usr/include/` without causing any problems?

Comment: NO! don't mess with location of system files. Instead use `pkg-config --cflags` or add an appropriate `-I` directive

Comment: I did define an `-I` directive and it solved the problem. Now I need to provide `make` with a library name. What is that name? I am looking for a library in `/usr/lib/` folder but I cannot find any folder or file with `libnl` in its name.

Comment: According to `pkg-config --libs libnl-3.0` the appropriate library directive is `-lnl-3` (corresponding to library name `libnl-3`)